# Gradle build error with Simpleframework

Tags: gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, simple-framework

I upload my library module to jcenter and I use this module with my application project.

I try to build my application it returns an error.

I searched this issue and This issue is due to be aware of what simpleframework.

I **have to use this library both** My library module and application module.

How can I solve this problem?

Gradle error msg is below

> trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":
>   Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library. This is often due to inadvertently
>   including a core library file in your application's project, when
>   using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If you are sure you're not
>   intentionally defining a core class, then this is the most likely
>   explanation of what's going on. However, you might actually be trying
>   to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may
>   have taken, for example, from a non-Android virtual machine project.
>   This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>   compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform. It is
>   also often of questionable legality. If you really intend to build a
>   core library -- which is only appropriate as part of creating a full
>   virtual machine distribution, as opposed to compiling an application
>   -- then use the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message. If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
>   building an application, then be forewarned that your application will
>   still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for
>   angry customers who find, for example, that your application ceases to
>   function once they upgrade their operating system. You will be to
>   blame for this problem. If you are legitimately using some code that
>   happens to be in a core package, then the easiest safe alternative you
>   have is to repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question
>   into your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
>   conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you
>   in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an
>   indication that the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain,
>   suffering, grief, and lamentation. 1 error; aborting Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My library build.gradle dependencies are below.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
}
```

My Application dependencies are below :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5'
    /*compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }*/
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2+'
    compile 'com.effectivelife:cokcok-support:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I add a configurations to my application project.

So my application build.gradle file is below.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'stax'
    compile.exclude module: 'stax-api'
    compile.exclude module: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2+'
    compile 'com.effectivelife:cokcok-support:1.0.1'
}
```